# I am trying to fetch json from a django view by jquery getjson but it is not working

Tags: jquery, python, json, django

If i save the json thrown from view function in json extension file it works, but i am not able to directly take data from my view function url.
I have even tried including html file as template and render it a using a new view and using {% url:thrower %} tag but it also didn't work

Below function throws data

```
def thrower(request):
    query=Category.objects.all()
    query=serializers.serialize('json',query)
    return  HttpResponse(query,content_type="application/json")

url
url(r'^thrower/$', views.thrower, name='thrower')

My jquery function and html

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#get-data').click(function () {

   $.getJSON('/thrower', 
    function(data) {
        // data is [{},{},{}]
        $.each(data, function(key, val) { 
            // val is { pk, model, {fields}}
            $("#show-data").append("Object id is: " + val.pk + ' of model: ' + val.model);
            $.each(val.fields, function(fieldname, field) {
                 $("#show-data").append(fieldname + ' : ' + field);
            }); 
        });
    }, "json");


  });
});


html file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Request JSON Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" id="get-data">Get JSON data</a>
    <div id="show-data"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


json from thrower function

[{"model": "bhu.category", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Test"}}, 

{"model": "bhu.category", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "test2"}}, {"model": "bhu.category", "pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "test3"}}, {"model": "bhu.category", "pk": 4, "fields": {"name": "deepak"}}, {"model":
```

Comment: what are you getting in chrome dev tools (networking tab)? 404?

Comment: Did you try to add breakpoint in chrome dev tool inside getJSON function to see if you get into this code?

Comment: Did you try to add slash to the json (like you define in url) $.getJSON('/thrower/', ...

Comment: I have tried ever permutation and combination but nothing is working.Network is showing 200 with same page again. I have tried creating new view an rendering my html into it but even that i not working

Comment: Did you console.log(data); ? do you see your json?

Comment: if the problem is in the server side, you can try to return HttpResponse(json.dumps(query), content_type="application/json")

Comment: my view is throwing json as i can see by visiting url.I think the problem is with the url in jquery code but i don't know ho to correct it

Comment: What is the last "json" in getJson("thrower", function (data) {...} , "json"); stand for? Look redundant to me. Did you try to put break point or alert inside the function? Did you try to add .fail(finction(){ alert(" fail")}); to see if u have any failure? BTW the first slash in the url is also redundant..

Comment: the error now i m getting is "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Can u update the code in the question so I could help u?

Comment: I forgot the ; after the alert(..)